# Python Invalid Syntax: Print and Elif statements

Tags: python, syntax

I am really new to Python and programming (2 days to be exact). I was messing around in idle trying to come up with a more complicated process than just print "Hello world." I was wondering if any of you could tell me why it is marking my print and elif statements invalid. I am using Python 2.7.10, thanks!

```
A = raw_input("Do you live in the US or Canada?")
if A == " US" or "Canada":
        print "Welcome!"
else:
    print "We're sorry, but your country is currently not supported!"

B = int(raw_input("How much is your package?")
        if B >= 25
            print "Your shipping is $4.00"
    elif B >= 50
        print "Your shipping is $8.00"
else:
    print "Congrats, your shipping is free!"
```

Comment: 1. indentation, 2. `if A == "US" or  A == "Canada":`

Comment: 3. Forgot to close parentheses on the `B =` line.

Comment: If you made this yourself, it's quite amazing for a 2-day learner. I've gotta say

Comment: I would suggest you try to solve a few math problems in Python next. Eventually, you can use it to cheat on math homework for school (you won't do that of course........)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the first thing you notice about python is that consistent indentation is not just a good idea, it is mandatory. Experienced programmers, whether they write Python or not, always do that anyway so it is no big deal. Use spaces (4 is the norm) and avoid tabs - change your editor to replace a tab with 4 spaces.

It is a bad idea to use float on money amounts because of rounding. Better to use a large type, like Decimal, or store the amount as an int in cents, then insert a decimal point when you display.  For simplicity I have stuck with using `float`, but be warned.

You have a number of logic errors in your code, as well as issues with style.  Programming style is not just about what looks nice, it is whether you can understand your code later, when you come back to it.

Style points:

Don't use UPPERCASE for variables.  By convention UPPERCASE is reserved for constants

Use meaningful variable names, not A and B

Here is a corrected program, with comments.  Please read the comments! :

```
# This is a comment, it is ignored by python
# This is used later on by sys.exit()
import sys

# Logically the user would enter "Yes" or "No" to this quesion,
# not US or Canada!
ans = raw_input("Do you live in the US or Canada? ")    # Notice the space after ?

# Note how the condition has been expanded
if ans == "US" or ans == "Canada":
    print "Welcome!" 
else: 
    print "We're sorry, but your country is currently not supported!"

    # Now what?  Your program just carried on.  This will stop it
    sys.exit()

# I'm using a floating point number for simplicity
amount = float(raw_input("How much is your package? "))

# I changed this around, since 50 is also >= 25!
# However, this is strange.  Usually the more you spend the LESS the shipping!
# You were missing the : after the condition
if amount >= 50:
    print "Your shipping is $8.00"
    amount += 8           # This adds 8 to the amount
elif amount >= 25:
    print "Your shipping is $4.00"
    amount += 4           # This adds 4 to the amount
else:
    print "Congrats, your shipping is free!"

# print the amount showing 2 decimal places, rounding
print "Amount to pay: $%.2f" % (amount)
```

You have plenty more to do.  Maybe cope with the user entering lower or mixed case letters for the country name - and ask yourself if the question is logical to the user.

Later you might want to have a list of valid countries, and use `in` to test if the user entered a valid country.  Then expand it to use a dictionary, indicating currency symbols, shipping amounts, and currency conversion rates for each country.

Enjoy Python!

Answer (score -3):

Fixed it for you :). Take a look to see what's different, and you will learn, young padawan:

```
A = raw_input("Do you live in the US or Canada?")

if A == "US" or A == "Canada":
    print "Welcome!"
else:
    print "We're sorry, but your country is currently not supported!"

B = float(raw_input("How much is your package?"))

if B >= 25:
    print "Your shipping is $4.00"
elif B >= 50:
    print "Your shipping is $8.00"
else:
    print "Congrats, your shipping is free!"
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, can you explain what difference float vs int does on the B= line? Thanks!

Comment: @Jack, `int()` only accepts integers, a.k.a. whole numbers. It'll actually raise an if you give it a string like `'23.4'`. `float()` will accept decimal number strings as well, such as `'23.4'`.

Comment: Bad idea to use float on money amounts because of rounding.  Better to use a large type, like Decimal, or store the amount as an int in cents, then insert a decimal point when you display.  See also https://code.google.com/p/python-money/

Comment: @cdarke, you're right of course, I just didn't want to overwhelm him. He'll get to that naturally at some point. But good to mention it here :).

Comment: @Jack: if you will go with this response, don't forget, per etiquette, to mark it as accepted. Just trying to help.